# Is there any way where x return y not 1?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way where x return y not 1?

```js
$("button").click(function(){
      var x = y = 1;      
      $("span").text(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Return X</button>
<div>Result : <span> </span></div>
```

Situation is like this.

```
var shippingProviders = "somthing"
this.Routerconfig[UrlService.SHIPPING_PROVIDERS] = shippingProviders;
```

here i want `shippingProviders` too

Comment: what are you  trying to get ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, expand a bit?

Comment: 2 up vote seriously ?

Comment: I'm curious to see where this is heading

Comment: Maybe the two people who upvoted this question because it is “clear” can explain what the question is about.

Comment: I don’t see how the first snippet relates to the second one in any way and it’s even less clear than before what you’re actually asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment expression evaluates the right hand side and assigns the resulting value to the left hand side.

Evaluating a variable (e.g. `shippingProviders`) results in the value the variable has (`"somthing"`). There is no way to get the name of a variable at runtime.

If you use the variable `shippingProviders`, then there is nothing that should stop you from using / writing the string `'shippingProviders'` for whatever you need it.

Comment: something like this? "shippingProviders : " + shippingProviders & split with :

Comment: In general I would suggest to use an object or an array, but that depends on the context.

Comment: ok. going ahed with object. thanks.